# indexOf() in Android when using Helper

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, indexing

I know that the below code gives the index of that particular element in java.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list .add("100");

Log.d("TAG",String.valueOf(list.indexOf("300")));
```

But how to get the index of an element while using a helper Class?

```
List<HelperClass> Arraylist= new ArrayList<>();

Arraylist.add(new HelperClass(name, email, phoneno));

Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(new HelperClass(Arraylist.indexOf(name,email,phoneno))));
```

I searched everywhere for this but couldn't find. Can someone tell me how to find index of a particular item in arraylist while using modal to add data?

Obviously what I have tried is wrong and it shows red line under the whole line but I just typed that code for your understanding of what I want to achieve. Can someone give me a way please?

Helper

```
 @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = getName() != null ? getName().hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (Email != null ? Emaail.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (PhoneNo!= null ? PhoneNo.hashCode() : 0);

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Helper)) return false;

    Helperthat = (Helper) o;

    if (getName() != null ? !getName().equals(that.getName()) : that.getName() != null)
        return false;
    if (Email != null ? !Email.equals(that.Email) : that.Email != null)
        return false;
    if (PhoneNo != null ? !PhoneNo.equals(that.PhoneNo) : that.PhoneNo != null)
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList#indexOf` uses the `Object#equals` comparison method.

If you want to be able to lookup a `HelperClass` instance inside a `Collection`, you need to provide your own, overridden, `equals` method, and possibly also the `hashCode` one, for use with other, specific, `Collection` implementations (`Map`, `Set`, etc.).

```
class HelperClass {
   ...

   @Override
   public boolean equals(final Object object) {
      if (object == this) {
        return true;
      }

      if (!(object instance of HelperClass)) {
         return false;
      }

      final HelperClass other = (HelperClass) object;
      return name.equals(other.name) &&
             email.equals(other.email) &&
             phone.equals(other.phone);
   }
}
```

You obviously need to have an appropriate `HelperClass` instance to find a match.

```
final String name = "Name";
final String email = "Email";
final String phone = "Phone";

final HelperClass first = new HelperClass(name, email, phone);
final HelperClass second = new HelperClass(name, email, phone);

final List<HelperClass> helpers = new ArrayList<>(8);
helpers.add(first);

final int index = helpers.indexOf(second); // index = 0
```

Comment: Do u need 2 class instance?

Comment: @MaiseeMiller well, if you have access to the "first" instance, you can use that one.

Comment: @MaiseeMiller I'll do it for you.

Comment: I autogenerated the equals and hashcode code and I havnt changed... Is there a problem with that? because im not even able to compile the code of indexOf properly

Comment: @MaiseeMiller if you have autogenerated your equals and hashCode, it must work. If not, post the code you're using here.

Comment: Look to the edited question. I have added the helper class

Comment: @MaiseeMiller there is a typo here "Helperthat = (Helper) o;". Seems good to me. Are you sure you're comparing the right objects? Also, add a "return true;" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf requires the object as input. If it does not find the object you are passing in, it will return -1. You need to pass the object whose location in the arraylist you are looking for as the input into the indexOf function.

**Solution :** 
create a HelperClass to pass into the indexOf method:

```
.indexOf(new HelperClass(name, email, phoneno));
```

However that change by itself will still return -1. See the api doc for indexOf:

> public int indexOf(Object o)
>
> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

It's using equals to decide whether it's found a match. You should have overridden the equals method on your HelperClass class, so it's using the default implementation in java.lang.Object, which compares the references, and only returns true if the two references HelperClass to the same object.

**Override equals and hashcode on your `HelperClass` class, like:**

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof HelperClass)) {
        return false;
    }
    HelperClass otherHelperClass = (HelperClass)other;
    return otherHelperClass.x == this.x && otherHelperClass.y == this.y;
}

@Override public int hashCode() {
    return x + y; // same values should hash to the same number
}
```

Comment: It still shows -1. Any idea why? I used "name.indexOf(new HelperClass(name, email, phoneno));"

Comment: and then it asked me to surround it with String.valueOf so my final code is "name.indexOf(String.valueOf(new HelperClass(name, email, phoneno, from)));

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't finished and I didn't notice that I've published the answer . CHeck it now I assure you it'll work (I had the same issue)

Comment: if I put name.indexOf(new HelperClass(name, email, phoneno)); its asking me to wrap using string.valueOf and I had already generated hashcode and equals in helper class

Comment: Look to the edited question. I have added the helper class